# Checkbox keeps state across components in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React JS, but I read about `<input>` that you have to save actual state in `onChange` like described here: [React DOC - Forms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

I have a list with a checkbox and I applied same behavior here in `CampaignsRow`

```
var campaignsData = [{Name: "First"}, {Name: "Second"}, {Name: "Third"}];

var CampaignsRow = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {checked: false};
    },
    checkedChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({checked: e.target.checked});
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.props.data.Name, this.state.checked);
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="cell checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.checkedChange}/>
                </div>
                <div className="cell campaignName">{this.props.data.Name}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var CampaignsTable = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var rows = this.props.campaigns.map(function(campaign) {
        return (
            <CampaignsRow data={campaign}/>
        );
    });

    return <div className="table">
        <div className="row header">
            <div className="cell checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/></div>
            <div className="cell campaignName">Name</div>
        </div>
        {rows}
    </div>
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<CampaignsTable campaigns={campaignsData} /> ,document.getElementById('reactContainer'));
```

My problem is, if I check the checkbox at the campaign with name **First** and then I remove first item by `campaignsData.shift()` (to simulate downloading new data from Server) and then render again, checkbox at **Second** campaign is checked.

What is the purpose of `this.state` when it is not attached to the instance. Render works fine, because in the console is printed `Second true`, so `this.state.checked` was moved from **First** to **Second** campaign.

Comment: Maybe adding key like `<CampaignsRow key={campaign.name} data={campaign} />` will help.

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/) looks good, except that you missed `key` attribute

Comment: do i get you right that if an item is checked it should be removed from the campaigns table?

Comment: @hyde No, but item could be removed by someone else. This removing was just simulation, when item is removed and data are synchronized with server. Than if you had checked item which is removed, check state is transferred to next checkbox..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add unique [`key`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html) property to multiple components, so that React can keep track of identities:

```
var rows = this.props.campaigns.map(function(campaign) {
    return (
        <CampaignsRow key={campaign.name} data={campaign}/>
    );
});
```